# Unable to create bundle on iTunes Connect for free app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunesconnect-analytics

I am trying to Create Bundle for uploading free iOS App to iTunes Connect. Create Button is disabled even after entering Name.

[image]

Create button is enabled only if I am adding existing Apps in Bundle which I am distributing free of cost. 
I am facing this issue after Apple has updated Agreement.
Can anybody help me out to resolve this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: any luck here? did you find any solution? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @SarimSidd : yup my issue is resolved. Follow the below steps given by Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to accept the new agreement.
Go into iTunes Connect, then agreements, tax and banking.
Click request on the two agreements at the top and agree to them.
Once you have agreed you will be instantly allowed access to create new apps.